# Borderless window layout does not look the same on different resolution

Tags: wpf, xaml, borderless

I have an issue where my controls disappear on different resolution and it happened after I set it to resize with grips and when you resize it with grips to make it smaller all my controls start to shrink and are not being "pushed" as it does on forms with a border

**on 1280x1024**

[image]

**on 1366x768**

[image]

```
    Title="omini_dækberegner" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
    MouseDown="Window_MouseDown" Topmost="True" x:Name="win"
    WindowStyle="None"
    Height="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}"
    Width="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}"
    ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
    AllowsTransparency="True" Visibility="Visible" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
    IsHitTestVisible="True" Loaded="win_Loaded">
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome 
    CaptionHeight="0"
    ResizeBorderThickness="5" />
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>

    <TabControl x:Name="tabControl"
                Background="#FF494949" BorderBrush="#FF494949" Foreground="#FF494949"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                Margin="0,52,0,-2" >
        <TabItem Header="Dækberegner" Background="#FF303030" Foreground="#FFEAEAEA"
                 BorderBrush="#FF303030" FontSize="16"
                 VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Grid  Background="#FF494949">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBox x:Name="bredebox_nu"
                         Margin="42,140,1014,697"
                         Height="24" Width="120"
                         TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FFEAEAEA" Background="#FF303030"
                         MaxLength="3" TabIndex="0" TextChanged="bredebox_nu_TextChanged" />
```

Comment: Check the margins of your controls.. there's probably some UI elements/settings that when re-sized, are causing your controls to disappear. did you design the Window using the resolution that works?

Comment: Would need to see the layout to diagnose. Although generally you shouldn't see a Height/Width set on a window that expects to be resized.

Comment: yes i designed it in the 1280x1024 but it also shrinks there when i resizing it with grips

i had also pasted the xaml for some of the controls that disapears

Comment: If your layout is filled with stuff I see like `Margin="42,140,1014,697"` then that's your problem, your layout was not created with resizing in mind.

Comment: so what do i need to do to achieve that?

Comment: using canvas instead of grid had solved it